# Conditional map function in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm taking an array of ([(String?, String)]) and want to drop the last 3 or 5 elements of the non-optional String, depending on the String.

If I know I'm dropping 5 I use

```
let strippedName = (data.map{ ($0.1).dropLast(5) } ).map{ String($0) }
```

however, as I said this is a conditional thing depending on the string within the array.

When I try

```
                    let strippedName = (data.map{
                        if ($0.1 == "a") {
                            return $0.1.first!
                        } else {
                        return $0.1.last!
                        }

                    } ).map{ String($0) }
```

(which is obviously not quite the finished article for my needs).

The example will crash on some inputs, that is irrelevant. I need to have an if statement in the map above (the detail of the if statement is not relevant). An alternative is any way to have a conditional map function in Swift (as is the question title).

As above, my requirement is "I'm taking an array of ([(String?, String)]) and want to drop the last 3 or 5 elements of the non-optional String, depending on the String."

I get an error on the last String() cast - Ambiguous use of init.

How can I take my array and use an if statement within my first map?

Comment: Can you show some sample input and outputs?

Comment: Your example is a little weird since you could just return "a" when you get a match and why force unwrap when the second item of the tuple is never nil?

Comment: which is obviously not quite the finished article for my needs. If I the example doesn't work (it doesn't) a full example won't work (it won't). The details are trivial and irrelevant; I want an If statement in a map function.

Comment: I understand that but it makes it hard to understand the question. If this is all there is to it than the posted answers should work, right?

Comment: You get downvoted for putting full problems if they aren't easy to understand. You write what you want, people don't read and make comments. I mean, the question is I want to put an if statement in a map. I've updated the question, but I'm sure they'll be issues with people seeing there is a forced unwrap now.

Comment: The original context has been there all the time: "I'm taking an array of ([(String?, String)]) and want to drop the last 3 or 5 elements of the non-optional String, depending on the String." I've written it again, below the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swift could not infer the complex closure return type, hence it is showing you the error "Ambiguous use of init()"

Specifying the return type explicitly solves the issue.

```
let data: [(String?, String)] = [("a","bBCDEA"), ("b","a"), (nil,"CBCDEB"), ("d","aBCDEF"), (nil,"a"), ("f","FBCDEC")]

var strippedName = (data.map { tuple -> String.Element in
  if (tuple.1 == "a") {
      return tuple.1.first!
  } else {
      return tuple.1.last!
  }
}).map{ String($0) }

print(strippedName) // ["A", "a", "B", "F", "a", "C"]

strippedName = (data.map{ ($0.1).dropLast(5) } ).map{ String($0) }

print(strippedName) // ["b", "", "C", "a", "", "F"]
```

Comment: This is swift, you don't need to use () around your swift conditions, `if tuple.1 == "a" {`works fine. Also you might want to change your sample data so at least one element satisfies the condition to make the answer clearer.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. For the sake of clarity, there's no harm in using () around conditions. I have changed sample data to make the answer clearer.

Answer (score 4):

Another way to solve it is to use reduce

```
let strippedName = data.reduce(into: []) { if $1.1 == "a" {$0.append($1.1)}}
```

---

**Update**

Trying to solve this as OP wants by using an `if` in the mapping. For my example here I use `compactMap` rather than `map`, this way anything that doesn't satisfy the `if` condition will be excluded from the array.

Since the return type of the closure is define to be String I don't need to do a second mapping

```
let strippedName = data.compactMap { t -> String? in
    if t.1 == "a" {
        return t.1
    }
    return nil
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is with anonimous closure and type inference, however, to get what you're trying in your second chunk of code, you can use filter instead of conditionals. With this you won't get error:

```
let strippedName = data.filter { $0.1 == "a" }.map { $0.1 }
```

and you can add `dropLast` to the end.